# Android - Incorporating SerachableDictionary sample into my app

Tags: java, android, search, sample

I am trying to incorporate the SearchableDictionary sample into my app to have a simple glossary search ability. If you are unfamiliar with the SearchableDictionary you click the search icon in the menu and enter your search term.  It suggest items based on your search and if you click go or enter on your keyboard it will pull up a list of items matching the search.  Selecting an item will bring up a full screen definition.

I have incorperated this and it works with one exception, when I hit go or enter on the keyboard after only a few letters the program force closes and does not bring up a list of matching terms.  All other aspects work, it suggests items when typing the term and clicking on an item will bring up its definition.

Here is a logcat of when the error happens.  I see that it happens in SearchableDictionary.java but cannot pinpoint the error.

tl;dr - App crashes when trying to list possible search matches.

```
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.SearchableDictionary}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.company.appname.SearchableDictionary.showResults(SearchableDictionary.java:112)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.company.appname.SearchableDictionary.handleIntent(SearchableDictionary.java:78)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.company.appname.SearchableDictionary.onCreate(SearchableDictionary.java:56)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-12 02:35:41.450: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  ... 11 more
```

Also, here is the full SearchableDictionary.java:

```
public class SearchableDictionary extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Because this activity has set launchMode="singleTop", the system calls this method
    // to deliver the intent if this actvity is currently the foreground activity when
    // invoked again (when the user executes a search from this activity, we don't create
    // a new instance of this activity, so the system delivers the search intent here)
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
        finish();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}

/**
 * Searches the dictionary and displays results for the given query.
 * @param query The search query
 */
private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                            new String[] {query}, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        // There are no results
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    } else {
        // Display the number of results
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

        // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                               R.id.definition };

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.search) {
        onSearchRequested();
    } else if (itemId == R.id.atcMainSearch) {
        Intent atcGoHome = new Intent(SearchableDictionary.this,
                mymainactivity.class);
        startActivity(atcGoHome);
    } else if (itemId == R.id.atcHelpSearch) {
        Intent atcAboutWeb = new Intent(SearchableDictionary.this,
                atcAboutWeb.class);
        startActivity(atcAboutWeb);
    } 
    return true;
}

}
```

Thank you to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and overlooked error caused this problem.  While trying to incorporate this capability I did not use all of the layouts and it was trying to reference one that was not there.  Once the layout was added to my project the app functioned as expected.